# Upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10, Blank screen with mouse pointer

Tags: upgrade, login, 14.10

I recently upgraded to 14.10 and now Ubuntu doesn't show the login screen any more.

The `.xsession-errors` file has some details (See below screenshot)

[image: Screenshot]

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 0):

When computer boot's choose the recovery mode option in grub. When it boots up you will get a menu. Select fail safe graphics option. It will ask you a couple questions you need to say yes to and then will attempt to boot up again. If this works, and once your up and running you can look into reinstall/update of driver if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I followed steps as you mentioned. Ubuntu started low graphics version in fail safe mode, then message appeared "stand by while display restarts". nothing happened for 2 mins, I selected resume the boot option. but I don't see the login screen. I had Ubuntu 14.04 running fine.

Comment: First line says GLX missing on display. Is this Nvidia? Were you using proprietary drivers or the open source prior to upgrade?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu as guest OS in VirtualBox running on Windows. Although my laptop has Nvidia card installed, I think Virtualbox doesn't use proprietary drivers. I want to rollback the entire upgrade, is it possible?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Could this be an issue of virtual box tools needing to be installed again (cause new OS). Don't the tools take care of display as well as USB stuff

Comment: I re-install virtualbox guest additions but that didn't fix the issue. Now, I am going to reinstall Ubuntu 14.10.